# how can I package resource files in a winrt app

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2019, windows-store, c++-winrt

What is the best approach to deploy "Resource" files within a WinRT app - Windows Store app? I am working on an app that will use a number of html and css template files to generate multiple reports.

How would I go about packaging these files (potentially within folders) to be deployed with the windows store app?

Ideally I would like to specify folders with the CSS files and Images that can be copied to an app directory during installation so I can reference them in the subsequent reports, but with permission issues in store apps I would be OK even if these could be deployed to the pictures folder or some other accessible location

I tried the assets group in visual studio 2019 but that only allows individual files to be included and I would have to programmatically extract them which seems pretty kludgy.

some additional details

1. UWP app using winRT/CPP
2. On the device (primarily surface tablet) I would like a folder hierarchy of appReports/css, appReports/img, appReports/fonts
3. I would prefer to create these subfolders within the Pictures folder so that the users can easily find the reports
4. I would be  using MSIX as the deployment strategy
5. If I was to bundle the template files into assets tree - I would need to do the following steps
   a. create the subdirectories css, img and fonts within Pictures from the app
   b. copy the template files to the respective folders

My thought was that there might be an easier way to do this external to the app since this is really only a one time setup situation

Comment: You could add folders with the CSS files and Images into UWP project directly, and they will deploy into app installation folder when app install.

Comment: *"I tried the assets group in visual studio 2019 but that only allows individual files to be included"* - That doesn't sound like there's an actual problem then. Though the question leaves much of the important detail out. Vital pieces of information include the application model (classic desktop, UWP, etc.) and the deployment strategy (MSIX, AppX, etc.).

Comment: Added details - I was hoping I could copy files into a folder structure as a one time setup procedure rather than doing it programmatically